# Navigation getting jammed sometimes on app

Tags: bug, ios-app

Sometimes I’ll go to a different page in the iOS app. This new page loads but the navigation gets stuck halfway where nothing at the top can be interacted with and I can’t swipe to go back a page. It’s not to hard to get out of (tapping an external link will fix it; you don’t usually have to close the app) but it’s super annoying.

Here is an example where it got stuck after I tapped a link taking me from ELU to ELL:

[image]

Here is one where it got jammed between search results and a question:

[image]

Here is an example where it got stuck between my inbox and a reply to my answer (I scrolled up to the top of the page):

[image]

These are only a couple of examples from the past two days. This happens to me all the time.

Addendum: Here’s an example where it shows the wrong site name:

[image]

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone SE
- OS Version: Version 12.1 (Build 16B92)